# How to share a dev certificate between a dev container and the host machine

Tags: .net, vscode-remote

I'm using a [dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) to develop ASP.NET Core apps and one of my requirements is being able to use HTTP**S** for connecting from my browser to the app running in the dev container.

Without dev containers, this is quite easy by using `dotnet dev-certs` [commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs).

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

However if I run this inside the dev container, the certificate won't be added to the trust store on the host machine, which is needed for the browser.

There is a ton of guidance on how to make this work with `docker run`:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md

But I'm not using `docker run`, I'm using the Remote Containers [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) in VS Code. I can't figure out how to make this work with Dev Containers in a platform-agnostic way.

Is it possible to share the certificate that I created on the host with my dev container?

Answer (score 2):

In a directory shared by host (macOS) and devcontainer (linux) I created a cert with dotnet on my host and imported it afterwards in the devcontainer.

on my host:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean # remove old certs
dotnet dev-certs https -ep {shared_dir}/mycert.pfx --trust -p mycertpassword
```

in my devcontainer:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean --import {shared_dir}/mycert.pfx -p mycertpassword
```

Comment: I wish it was possible to automate this